# Как в С++11 узнать состояние потока?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Как в С++11 узнать состояние потока, то есть работает или нет такой-то поток?

Comment: Вы про std::thread?

Comment: Такого средства из коробки в C++ нет. Распишите Вашу задачу подробнее, чтобы Вам могли предложить альтернативу.

Comment: Если предложенный ответ Вас удовлетворят, пожалуйста, отметьте его как лучший(галочку нажать)

Answer (score 12):

Как вы объясните системе, состояние какого потока Вам нужно проверить? Ваш вопрос принципиально некорректен.

Предупреждая возможный ответ: по id в ОС нельзя, т.к. номер может быть занят уже другим потоком, если один перестал работать.

Если же у Вас уже есть какой-то handle потока, то узнать его состояние можно средствами того же API, средствами которого Вы этот handle получили.

В частности, если речь идет именно об std::thread, то этот вопрос дубликат вот этого: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094422/how-to-check-if-a-stdthread-is-still-running

**UPD:**
Для `std::thread` есть несколько вариантов, по-сути являющихся вариациями передачи флага о завершении в поток и проверки этого флага.

Вариант для `std::thread` + `std::promise`:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Создаём объект promise и получаем из него future.
    std::promise<bool> p;
    auto future = p.get_future();

    // Запускаем задачу в отдельном потоке
    std::thread t([&p] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        p.set_value(true);
    });

    // С помощью ожидания на future мы получаем статус потока
    auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));

    if (status == std::future_status::ready) {
        std::cout << "Thread finished" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Thread still running" << std::endl;
    }

    t.join();
}
```

Вариант с `std::thread` + `std::atomic`:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::atomic<bool> done(false); // Атомарный флаг.

    //Всё как и в прошлом примере, но теперь используем atomic вместо promise
    std::thread t([&done] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        done = true;
    });

    if (done) {
        std::cout << "Thread finished" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Thread still running" << std::endl;
    }

    t.join();
}
```

Вариант с `std::thread` и `std::packaged_task`, наиболее "чистый" с точки зрения архитектуры решения, т.к. решение достигается средствами языка, а не жонглированием флагами:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    //Создаём packaged_task, передав в неё задачу и получаем объект future.
    std::packaged_task<void()> task([] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    });
    auto future = task.get_future();

    //Запускаем задачу в выделенном потоке.
    std::thread t(std::move(task));

    auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));


    if (status == std::future_status::ready) {
        //Поток завершён, т.е. задача, переданная в packaged_task завершилась(дошла до return)
        // ...
    }

    t.join();
}
```

Comment: да это подходит: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094422/how-to-check-if-a-stdthread-is-still-running

Comment: @sitev_ru, рад был помочь

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно узнать запущен ли поток то проверяйте на joinable. Если же узнать завершилось ли выполнение работы потока, то можно воспользоваться условными переменными (condition_variable)